# TYPE_PHONE overlay view doesn't allow child GridView to capture onItemClick event

Tags: java, android, gridview, overlay

My applications draws an overlay which has a `GridView` as it's child. All the clicks are being captured by the overlay veiw's `onTouch` event and nothing is passed to the `GridView`'s `onItemClick` event. The code which creates it is:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
TaskBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_overlay, null);
TaskBarViewParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(TaskBarInactiveWidth, TaskBarHeight,
            LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
TaskBarViewParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.addView(TaskBarView, TaskBarViewParams);
```

**Note:** This problem only comes into picture on **API levels 16 and up**. The `GridView` captures it's `onItemClick` and the overlay captures it's `onTouch` properly as it should below API level 16.

Am I missing a flag or something?

Comment: Is it such an idiotic question or lack of details?

Comment: I mean seriously, why do my all questions always remain unanswered here?

Comment: have you tried disabling the click on the overlay before adding the view?

Comment: Do you mean `.setClickable(false)`?
Yes, upon your suggestion. But didn't help...